# Dois selects em um while com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá, estou migrando do MySQL para o PDO e estou com dificuldade em colocar numa tabela dois selects.

```
try{
        $CON = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tcc", 'root', '1234');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Erro : ".$e->getMessage();
    }

    $select = "select * from MATERIA";
    $resultado = $CON->query($select);

    $select2 = "select * from ALUNO";
    $resultado2 = $CON->query($select2);



    while($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) and  $row2=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['NOME']."</td><td>".$row2['NOME']."</td>";
    }
```

O problema é que, quando acaba os resultados da consulta 1, ele para de listar os outros alunos, e eu gostaria que ele continuasse a escreve-los.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido o que fez. Qual é o seu objetivo?

Comment: Preciso listar numa tabela onde a primeira coluna são os alunos cadastrados e na segunda as matérias cadastradas no banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como falaram nos comentários, faz pouco sentido seu código. Seria melhor se falasse o que pretende, talvez alguma print do projeto.

Enfim, com algumas poucas modificações isso aqui vai te ajudar.

```
<?php

try {
    $conn = new pdo('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tcc', 'root', '1234', [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Erro: {$e->getMessage()}";
    die;
}

$stmtMaterias = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `MATERIA`');
$stmtAlunos = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `ALUNO`');

try {
    $stmtMaterias->execute();
    $stmtAlunos->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Erro: {$e->getMessage()}";
    die;
}

$materias = $stmtMaterias->rowCount() ? $stmtMaterias->fetchAll() : [];
$alunos = $stmtAlunos->rowCount() ? $stmtAlunos->fetchAll() : [];

if (count($alunos) >= count($materias)) {
    foreach ($alunos as $key => $value) {
        echo '<tr>';

        if (isset($materias[$key]['NOME'])) {
            echo "<td>{$materias[$key]['NOME']}</td>";
        }

        if (isset($value['NOME'])) {
            echo "<td>{$value['NOME']}</td>";
        }
    }
} else {
    foreach ($materias as $key => $value) {
        echo '<tr>';

        if (isset($value['NOME'])) {
            echo "<td>{$value['NOME']}</td>";
        }

        if (isset($alunos[$key]['NOME'])) {
            echo "<td>{$alunos[$key]['NOME']}</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: então, eu quero mostrar todos os dados nas suas colunas com um while só, por ter que sempre atribuir as tags do <td> e <tr>, porém se eu deixo o while como postei, acontece isso:
 http://prntscr.com/ffyihq, e se eu tiro a segunda condição, ela fica "meio" certa: http://prntscr.com/ffyiti

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Editei a resposta. Veja se agora atende ao que você precisa.

Comment: deu certo, apesar de ter colocado as matérias no lugar errado, era isso que eu queria!
Gostaria de saber como o fez, não entendi metade do código que você mandou, você poderia me passar algum tutorial que explique isso para um novato na programação? 
Novamente eu agradeço pela ajuda!